# Spring EL (SpEL) code execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to use the SpEL for evaluating some user input. But that opens a security hole because the SpEL enginge also executes code and could start classes and access static objects. For example T(System).exit(0) exits the system.

Is it possible to prevent this type of code executions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to avoid this is to never evaluate user input in the expression language.

You will pretty much never be able to enumerate and therefore prevent execution of all possible "bad" code.

Instead, you can use user input as environment variables (strings, numbers) with fixed EL-expressions.